# How can we use a neural network as a fixed layer in optimization?

Tags: optimization, neural-network, pytorch

I have train a neural network using pytorch.
I want to use it as a component (without updating the weight) in a optimization pipeline. I plan that optimization will be implemented in PyTorch.
How can I do that?

Comment: Instantiate your trained model (module) with requires_grad=False in the new training setup. It will not train but will still pass gradients if any of its inputs require training (see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#locally-disable-grad-doc).

Comment: Yes@Daugmented is right. You can just load trained weights to the model and set requires_grad=False you can use it as a component during optimization.